# Function that samples region for daily images within multiple years

Tags: google-earth-engine, function

I am trying to sample daily meteorological data from 1990 to 2018 within a region and export as a CSV file. How can I write a function within a function to filter first by year and then by day of year? Here is the syntax that I have so far. Is there is a faster way to do this?

```
var dataset=Gridmet.filter(ee.Filter.date('1990-01-01','2018-12-31'));
var bands = ['tmmx','rmax','rmin','tmmn','srad','th','pr'];            

 var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
                  ee.List.sequence(1991,2019).map(function(year){
 var data1 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year,year,'year'))
  return data1.filterBounds(CA).set('year',year);

  var imgColPerday = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
                  ee.List.sequence(1,366).map(function(day){
  var image = data1.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(day,day,'day_of_year'))
        .select(bands).mean();
  image=image.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat());
  return image.set('day_of_year', day)}));// set the day
 }));

 var data =  ee.FeatureCollection(imgCol.map(function(image){

 // calculate data
  var MeteorCA= image.sampleRegions({   
  collection: CA,
  scale: 4000
  }).map(function(feat){
  return feat.set('day_of_year',image.get('day_of_year').set('year',image.get('year')));
  });  

   return MeteorCA;
   })).flatten(); 

   //Exporting data to google drive
   var polyOut = MeteorCA.select(['.*'],null,false);

   Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: polyOut,
    description:'MeteorCA',
    folder: 'MeteorCA90',
    });
```